# How to Make Encryption (c1, c2) Tuple Explicit using Bouncy Castle ElGamal and javax.crypto.Cipher

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, elgamal

To encrypt a message with ElGamal scheme in java code, I proceed as follow:

```java
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Elgamal/NOne/NoPadding", "BC");
KeyPaireGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ElGamal", "BC");
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

generator.initialize(512, random);
KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();

String message = "myMessageToEncrypt";
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pair.getPublic(), random);
[]byte cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message);
```

I know from the ELGamal scheme that `cipherText` byte array contains (c1, c2) and I need to access c1 as an BigInteger.

So my question is: how to make the conversion between the byte array and the tuple (c1, c2) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `byte[]` with the ciphertext has twice the length of the key size, where the first half corresponds to `c0` and the second half to `c1`. The conversion of `ci` is achievable e.g. with [`new BigInteger(1, ci)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,byte%5B%5D)).

Verification is easily possible by performing the decryption manually with the `BigInteger`s converted in this way:

```
int keysizeBits = 512;

Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

// Key generation
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ElGamal", "BC");
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
generator.initialize(keysizeBits, random); 

KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
BCElGamalPublicKey publicKey = (BCElGamalPublicKey)pair.getPublic();
BCElGamalPrivateKey privateKey = (BCElGamalPrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();

// Encryption
byte[] input = "abcdefgh".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ElGamal/None/NoPadding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, random);
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(input);
System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + Hex.toHexString(ciphertext));//new String(cipherText));

// Decryption
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
System.out.println("Plaintext : " + new String(plaintext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

// Manual decryption 
// 1. Convert c0/c1 into BigInteger
byte[] c0 = new byte[keysizeBits/8];
byte[] c1 = new byte[keysizeBits/8];
System.arraycopy(ciphertext, 0,  c0, 0, keysizeBits/8);
System.arraycopy(ciphertext, c0.length,  c1, 0, keysizeBits/8);
System.out.println("c0        : " + Hex.toHexString(c0));
System.out.println("c1        : " + Hex.toHexString(c1));
BigInteger c0BI = new BigInteger(1, c0); 
BigInteger c1BI = new BigInteger(1, c1); 

// 2. Decrypt with c0BI^(-privBI) * c1BI
BigInteger privateKeyBI = privateKey.getX();
BigInteger pBI = privateKey.getParameters().getP();
BigInteger plaintextBI = c0BI.modPow(privateKeyBI.multiply(new BigInteger("-1")), pBI).multiply(c1BI).mod(pBI); 

System.out.println("Plaintext : " + new String(plaintextBI.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

with e.g. the following output:

```
Ciphertext: adc32bbd23d80489db5843e26b26c58062a2369912915025574fd8598b8c72665e0a922ad8897719e1f9b0e3fb76e275ed15194534399781017e43c24a92cc77b13a256ff27e12667cc0f5876d1873368449b5a60ecc7a60a6b92f2640608f21dc86e7effe1dc4038b02b8c6c9d7ac03bd2e7d66d803d2a19f459ffeedfcff46
Plaintext : abcdefgh
c0        : adc32bbd23d80489db5843e26b26c58062a2369912915025574fd8598b8c72665e0a922ad8897719e1f9b0e3fb76e275ed15194534399781017e43c24a92cc77
c1        : b13a256ff27e12667cc0f5876d1873368449b5a60ecc7a60a6b92f2640608f21dc86e7effe1dc4038b02b8c6c9d7ac03bd2e7d66d803d2a19f459ffeedfcff46
Plaintext : abcdefgh
```

Note that a key size of 512 bits is too small nowadays, see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/55036), and a missing padding is insecure, e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44448-3_3.pdf).

Comment: Where can you find the specifications for the algorithm ? I was not able to find it in the bouncy castle source code...

Comment: @Golddy - I didn't need the implementation of BouncyCastle at all for this, just the definition of ElGamal, s. e.g. [ElGamal encryption - Decryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption#Decryption). I assumed that BC implemented it correctly ;-)